# Adding an element <string, pointer> to boost unordered hashmap

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost unordered hashmap in C++ and I am unable to add elements to my hash map (my program has a segmentation fault). I am very new to C++ and the majority of my code (except the hash map handling) is C code. Could you please point out the problem.

```
// my simplified code

struct Record
{
        char *data;

};

typedef boost::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<Record*> > MAP;
typedef std::pair<std::string,std::vector<Record*> > PAIR;

struct OuterRelation
{
        short num_keys;
        short join_key_ndx;
        MAP hash_table;
};

OuterRelation *outer_relation = (OuterRelation *) malloc (sizeof(OuterRelation)) ;

Record *new = (Record *) malloc(sizeof(Record));
new->data = "somestring";

outer_relation->hash_table[new->data].push_back(new);
```

The problem is in the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STOP USING `malloc`. That's for C. Correct syntax would be:

`OuterRelation *outer_relation = new OuterRelation;`

Your use of `malloc` has allocated enough space for the OuterRelation struct alone. This might be enough if the struct contained only plain-old-data. However, the `hash_table` member is a class and using `malloc` has left it uninitialised.

`new` is (at its most basic) a combination of `malloc` and a call to the `new`'d object's constructor. The constructor for your struct will in turn call the constructors of its members, including the map. The map's constructor will initialise its data members.

You also need to stop using `new` as a variable name. That clashes with the `new` C++ keyword.

Comment: If I would like to free OuterRelation at the end of my program, does C++ offer free(outer_relation) construct? Is it a common practice to do such frees or do I leave it to the garbage collector?

Comment: Call `delete outer_relation;`. `delete` calls the object's destructor then frees its memory. C++ has no garbage collection. (Well, technically garbage collection libraries exist, but I haven't seen code which uses one yet.)